# How to find $f^{(4)}(0)$ using MacLaurin/Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to find $f^{(4)}(0)$ using MacLaurin/Taylor series for $f(x)=\dfrac { 1 }{ 1-x^ 2 }$

When I expanded it using MacLaurin series formula, I was getting the wrong answer and my series is totally different from the answer...

I couldn't understand the answer I have. Can anyone please show how to do this problem?

Comment: Hint: What if $|x^2|<1$? Do you know about the geometric series?

Comment: Maybe you can show us the answer you do not understand, so that we can see what your doubt is.

Comment: Let $x^2 = X$. Maybe it will look familiar after that

Comment: Is there any direct taylor series expansion formula for this

Comment: You *can* just do the derivatives by brute force, but because you are asked for derivatives at zero, it is easier to take advantage of the "known" geometric series. Doing all the derivatives will produce a whole bunch of terms that will just be zero when you plug in $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have for $\vert h\vert<1$

$$\frac1{1-h}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty h^n$$
so for $h=x^2$ we get

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(p)}(0)}{p!}x^p$$
hence
$$f^{(4)}(0)=4!$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^2)^n =\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}= 1 + 0\cdot x + x^2 + 0\cdot x^3 + x^4 + \cdots ...$$

Comment: How did you convert it into sigma notation

Comment: This is the so called geometric series. It holds: $\frac{1}{1-q}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n$ for $|q|<1$